# Nuclear state notation $J^\pi$

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, terminology, notation, parity

I have learned from nuclear physics literature that a nuclear state can be denoted as $J^\pi$, where $J$ is the spin and $\pi$ is the parity, such as $0^+, 1^+$. But when I read some papers on nuclear physics, I found that they might also have a subscript, like $2^+_1, 2^-_2$ state of $^{210}\rm Po$. So what's meaning of this subscript, is that the angular momentum along $z$-direction?

Comment: Hmm.  The $z$-axis projection seems unlikely because even stable nuclear states are tough to polarize. Total isospin probably isn't a good quantum number in a nucleus as heavy as polonium, and polonium doesn't seem to have rotational bands that might be indexed in this way.  If you can link to a paper where you've seen this notation, we can probably figure it out, but this isn't enough to go on.

Answer (score -1):

Those refer to the first and second excited states.

Comment: Can you link to a paper which uses this notation in this way?